# Create dir with Qt and Windows' "CreateDirectory" return -1, error

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I wanted to make a simple application:

[image]

In line edit user should give a path to the directory he/she wants to create in a working directory (the path should always look like this: ./dirname - for now on I dont handle any errors, assuming everything is ok) and when he/she clicks ok button, there should be created a dir named 'dirname'.

But when I pass path, lets say './testdir' and click ok, my app exits and "ERROR IN CREATEDIRECTORY" is shown and of course it doesnt create a dir. What is wrong and how to fix this?

Im using Qt Creator 2.8.1
based on Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit) on Windows XP.

Heres the code :

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:

    void createdir();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "Windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string GetLastErrorStdStr()
{
  DWORD error = GetLastError();
  if (error)
  {
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD bufLen = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        error,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );
    if (bufLen)
    {
      LPCSTR lpMsgStr = (LPCSTR)lpMsgBuf;
      std::string result(lpMsgStr, lpMsgStr+bufLen);

      LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

      return result;
    }
  }
  return std::string();
}

static const wchar_t *GetWC(const char *c)
{
    const size_t cSize = strlen(c)+1;
    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
    mbstowcs (wc, c, cSize);

    return wc;
}

LPCWSTR castPath(const char *path)
{
    WCHAR str3[1024];
    MultiByteToWideChar( 0,0, path, strlen(path), str3, strlen(path)+1);
    LPCWSTR cstr4 = str3;
    return cstr4;
}

static void makeDir(const char *path)
{
    if(CreateDirectory(castPath(path), NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR IN CREATEDIRECTORY\n");
        std::cout << GetLastErrorStdStr() << "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(createdir()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createdir()
{
    makeDir(ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str());
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>OK</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass just `'testdir'` as a path to create a directory?

Comment: @vahancho: No, it doesnt work. I just came up with a new idea - and I think it could be the issue. When I build some applications on VisualStudio sometimes I have to change 'Character Set' from 'Use Unicode Character Set' to ''Use Multi-Byte Character Set' to get it work well. Could it be the issue here? How to change 'Character Set' in QtCreator?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `CreateDirectory`. It tells you how to get more information in case of an error. I suggest that you follow that advice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: sure I tried. My modified code: http://pastie.org/private/ah0uccx0gux8bbcx1vpmzg but it doesnt help much really ...

Comment: Beyond that, the cast is totally bogus. What on earth possessed you to do that?! You are coding in C++ so if you have to cast, use C++ style casts and understand what you are doing. But when the compiler told you that you were passing the wrong type of parameter you should not have ignored it!!!

Comment: You tried? Well, what happened. Remember that we cannot see your screen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: 'Cannot create file' and thats all actually ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any reason you don't simply do `QDir::currentPath().mkpath(ui->lineEdit->text())`?

besides that `LPCWSTR` is a `wchar_t*` (which is different from simply char*) so you'd need more conversion than just a cast

```
static void makeDir(const wchar_t *path)
{
    if(CreateDirectory((LPCWSTR)path, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR IN CREATEDIRECTORY\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

and calling it with

```
makeDir(ui->lineEdit->text().toStdWString().c_str());
```

will fix it

Comment: ok, is there any other way than changing path to `wchar_t`? I need it to be const char...

Comment: you can instead use `CreateDirectoryA` which will take a `char*`

Comment: @yak Why would you want to do that? You'll no longer support Unicode, and Windows will only convert your 8 bit text into 16 bit UTF-16 internally. Pointless to give up international support.

Comment: I'd advise keeping both the `char*` and the `wchar_t*` version at least and keeping to the `wchar_t*` version as much as possible. or just use the Qt solution which I supplied at the top of the answer

Comment: @ratchetfreak Why keep `char*`? If it were me I'd do it the Qt way for sure. If you have to call Win32 APIs, then use the native Windows encoding, UTF-16. No place for ANSI encoding these days.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `CreateDirectoryW` since you have are compiling a wide character application. You write `CreateDirectory`, but that's a macro that expands to either `CreateDirectoryW` or `CreateDirectoryA`.

If you have ANSI encoded text then you can call `CreateDirectoryA`. But you should not do that since it means you will not cater for international text. It's easy enough to ask the `QString` to supply UTF-16 encoded text. Use `toStdWString` and then call `c_str()` on that object. Even better, use the Qt functionality and stop digging around in platform specific Win32 code.

When you call a Windows API function and it fails, read the documentation to find out how to diagnose the failure. In this case you are told to call `GetLastError`. So, you should do so.

But the most important thing to learn is that when the compiler tells you that your types do not match, simply casting away the compiler error is never the solution! All that does is leave the error in place, and carry on regardless. You convert a compile time error into a runtime error. The former is always preferable.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it by doing that it way: http://pastie.org/private/2jogzm0wiwc7zlipmdeo2q. Its ok, right?

Comment: That's really poor. You convert from the internal QString representation to ANSII. Then back to wide. You should use the code provided by @ratchet.